# How does a reference function "int &foo();" work?

Tags: c++, function, reference

I'm not really sure if you call it "reference function" but my teacher showed us a code that declared a function like a reference variable and I don't get the logic behind it.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int &max(int &x, int &y)
{
    if(x > y)
        return x;
    return y;
}

int main()
{
    int x, y;
    cout << "Enter 2 #s";
    cin >> x >> y;

    y = 3;
    max(x, y) = 1000;

    cout << endl;
    cout << "X: " << x << endl;
    cout << "Y: " << y << endl;
    cout << max(x, y) << endl; 

    max(x, y) = 1000;
    x = 5;

    cout << endl;
    cout << "X: " << x << endl;
    cout << "Y: " << y << endl;
    cout << max(x, y) << endl; 
}
```

Comment: What exactly don't you get?

Comment: Note: for compiler it does not matter if you write `int &max(...)` or `int& max(...)` or `int & max()` or even `int&max(...)` so do not rely on that, and do not think `&` applys to function if it is written that way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not a reference function, rather it returns a reference to x or y in the expressions

```
return x;
```

and

```
return y;
```

Maybe this becomes clearer to you by noting that the the definition you gave in the question is equivalent to the following expression where the & is written next to int rather than max.

```
int& max(int &x, int &y)
{
    if(x > y)
        return x;
    return y;
}
```

Comment: It could equally return a reference to x

Answer (score 2):

It's not a reference function, but the **return value** of the function is a reference. You can read the function like so: `int& max(int &x, int &y)`. Here's more information: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/returning_values_by_reference.htm

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the nomenclature means that the function is to return a reference to an integer. Exactly how it is to do this I don't really know. I am not accustomed to seeing a function declared in this way, and I would probably change the declaration altogether.